# Get and print h2 text to another div with jquery

Tags: jquery

I would like to get product name text from h2 tag and pass it into another div as list element. I'd like this event on clicking add-to-cart button.

(I have more product-item article elements)

Here is my HTML. Thanks all help!

```
<article class="product-item">
    <div class="product-title title-preorder">
        <h2><a href="#">This is my product name here</a></h2>
        <span class="preorder">
        Avaible
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-params">
        <div class="product-img">
            <img src="/image/10428.jpg" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="product-details">
            My description here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-cart">
        <div class="price">
            $45 
        </div>
        <div class="amount">
            <input id="345346" value="1" class="spinner" /> 
        </div>
        <a class="add-to-cart" ><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart</a>
    </div>
</article>

<div class="product-list">
    <ul>
        <li>I'd like to print h2 text here
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: If none of the answers worked or you are still facing trouble let me know so I can help

Answer (score 0):

You can use [text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/) to get the header text and [append()](http://api.jquery.com/append/) to add new list items

```js
$('.add-to-cart').click(function(){
  $('.product-list ul').append('<li>'+$('h2').text()+'</li>');
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<article class="product-item">
    <div class="product-title title-preorder">
        <h2><a href="#">This is my product name here</a></h2>
        <span class="preorder">
        Avaible
        </span>
    </div>
    <div class="product-params">
        <div class="product-img">
            <img src="/image/10428.jpg" alt="image">
        </div>
        <div class="product-details">
            My description here
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="product-cart">
        <div class="price">
            $45 
        </div>
        <div class="amount">
            <input id="345346" value="1" class="spinner" /> 
        </div>
        <a class="add-to-cart" ><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Add to Cart</a>
    </div>
</article>

<div class="product-list">
    <ul>
        <li>I'd like to print h2 text here
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/gsd306hj/):

```
$('.add-to-cart').click(function () {
  $('.product-list').find('li').text($('.product-title').find('a').text());
});
```

Comment: I have 3 product-item article with 3 add-to-cart button. This solution almost works but print all 3 h2 text in the list item. So now I have 3 names in it. Is it possible to print only the current text?

Comment: what do you mean by current text ? Can you please throw some light on it ?

Comment: See there are lots of ways for doing this . Either you can have checkboxes besides every product so that user selects which are to be added in the cart Or you can show all the product links but don't show the Add To Cart button for now , then on click on any product the Add To Cart button will be visible and then you can add the item to the cart .

Answer (score 0):

I solved it, with your help. I had to use "closest" method in the function, now it works perfectly.

```
$('.add-to-cart').click(function(){
   $('#cart-content-inner ul').append('<li>'+$(this).closest(".product-item").find('h2 a').text()+'</li>');
});
```